# Call AJAX with Vue.js and Vue resource in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm making AJAX request in Laravel with Vue.js and Vue resource.

I have view:

```
{{Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'id' => 'main-form'])}}
{{Form::text('param1', null, ['id' => 'param1', 'class' => 'form-control'])}}
{{Form::text('param2', null, ['id' => 'param2', 'class' => 'form-control'])}}
<input @click="sendIt($event)" type="submit" value="Check prices" class="btn btn-success btn-theme" />
{{Form::close()}}
```

I have js:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
methods: {
sendIt: function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var token = $('[name="_token"]').val();
        this.$http.post('/data').then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }, (response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/data', 'MainController@data');
```

And controller:

```
public function data() 
{
    $msg = $this->test(); //method that retrieves data from db
    return response()->json(['msg'=> $msg], 200);
}
```

It gives me post 500 internal server error

In response I have this headers:

```
Cache-Control
Content-Type
Date
Phpdebugbar-Id
Server
Status
Transfer-Encoding
X-Powered-By
```

In network in my data site I have response headers without token, request headers with token and I have token in Request Payload.

If I change method to get I have same error but if I change method to get and if I remove from my controller part of code where I retrieve data from db and just pass string to json (example:

```
$msg = 'test';
return response()->json(['msg'=> $msg], 200);
```

I have success and I can output test on page.

So I'm not sure if it's some problem with token or something else. 
I tried and this:

```
var token = $('[name="_token"]').val();
this.$http.post('/prices', {_token:token})
```

but nothing. Same error again.

If I add this:

```
http: {
    headers: {
  X-CSRF-TOKEN: document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content')
    }
},
```

I have syntax error on page load.

If I change to this:

```
http: {
    headers: {
  Authorization: document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content')
    }
}
```

I got internal server error again.

And this is my token in main view:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" id="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

EDIT:

This part works if I add quotes around x-csrf-token but still I have token mismatch error.

```
http: {
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content')
    }
},
```

Comment: Have you checked your log file? (`storage/logs/laravel.log`). I would imagine there is already a fair amount in there so you might be better off deleting the file, and trying your request again, and then you should have more information on your error. Alternatively, if you go to the preview tab in your console then error should be in there as well.

Comment: I cleared log file but nothing new happens. But in preview I got TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68: so it's about token. But I sent it :|

Comment: Do you know what version of Vue Resource you're using?

Comment: Vue version is 2.1.6 and resource is 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but in your example at the top you have:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
```

However, in your main view file you have:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" id="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

You should be able to simply change `$('meta[name=_token]')` to `$('meta[name=csrf-token]')` (so they match).

Furthermore, the reason you had a syntax error with `X-CSRF-TOKEN: ...` is because you can't use hyphens in key names unless you wrap them in quotes i.e. `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': ...`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed it but same errors again. Same headers are sent and same token mismatch error is shown. But now I don't have error on page load if I set http headers with x-csrf in quotes.

Comment: @KondukterCRO Are `window.Laravel.csrfToken` and the token in the request header the same?

Comment: Yes they are same